# Redirect issues

Tags: magento-1.7, redirect

This question has been answered before, but none of the answers work for me, and the questions are old so I didn't just want to add a Me To. Here is my specific situation:

Production server on a shared host, Magento 1.7.0

I am trying to create a test environment in preparation for updating the site to 1.9.2. I did the following:

1. disabled and flushed all caches
2. made a backup of the database using `mysqldump`
3. created a new database
4. loaded the new database from my backup using `mysql`
5. created a new directory for the test environment `magento-1.7.0`, production is in `magento`
6. copied production site to test environment using `cp magento/ magento-1.7.0/`
7. set pointers to the new database in `magento-1.7.0/app/etc/local.xml`
8. changed secure base url to `https://test.mydomain.com` in `core_config_data`
9. changed unsecure base url to `http://test.mydomain.com` in `core_config_data`
10. deleted `magento-1.7.0/var/cache` just to make sure it was gone
11. deleted `magento/var/cache` just to make sure it was gone
12. checked for compilation (none)
13. checked `/tmp/` for a `magento` directory or anything like it (none)
14. tested my new environment by pointing my browser to `test.mydomain.com` (note - mydomain.com is not the real domain name)
15. site still redirects to `www.mydomain.com`

I looked at the network response header in firefox, and found `location: www.mydomain.com`. The response code was 302. What else do I need to check for?

Comment: Did you check if your Magento store is using cache in `db` mode? If yes, the cache will be on `core_cache_option`. Or you can just change your `local.xml` to use `files` cache storage.

Comment: All cache options are disabled. All the values in `core_cache_option` are 0.